# How do I select an iframe on selenium?

Tags: html, selenium, iframe, continuous-integration

I'm trying to do an script on selenium, but I'm struck when I have to select a combofield who is allocated on an iframe, I've searched over this site and all over the web but the only answers are for junit format...And I need to do this in HTML Format because I don't have access to the code. Thank you!

[Image][1]
[Image 2][2]

Comment: We need an HTML content of the form or a URL to the target page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer in the "image 2" I show the code from the field where I want to select the combofield

Comment: And sorry but the website is from the government, so nobody outside the intranet could enter. I could request the access from other people outside the intranet if I have hopes to answer my question

Comment: If you can upload in the iFrame, Selenium has focus on the correct window. It you can select a value in another control (in the same window) your selector is probably wrong. Can you post your code, and the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it...So I'll tell how I made it

> COMMAND - TARGET - VALUE
>
> Focus - Iframe -
>
> Click -"element on the iframe" -
>
> sendKeys - "element on the iframe but in different format" - Value you want

---

In my case i used the one who has this format:

> //div[9]/span/span/span/span[2]/div/input

Hope this help other people.